# Regex not capturing when missing html tag attribute

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm having some trouble making this regex work when the html link doesn't have the `href="http://www.example.com"`. The `<ul class='social'>(...)</ul>` is always there on each page but the some anchor tags miss the `href` attribute.

It's here that my attempts are failing because when the `href=""` is there I'm able to capture the group with

`<a href="(.*?)" id="facebooklink" style="display:none;" class="facebook facebooklink" title="Become a fan on Facebook">Become a fan on Facebook<span></span></a>`

On the other side, when the case is like the one below, if one or more `href` are missing it will not capture even the ones which have the `href` attribute and value. In my example bellow it should capture at least the https://twitter.com/StackOverflow group.

The regex I'm using can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/iJ9tC7/12

```
<ul class="social">
    <li>
        <a id="facebooklink" style="display:none;" class="facebook facebooklink" title="Become a fan on Facebook">Become a fan on Facebook<span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow" id="twitterlink" style="display:none;" class="twitter twitterlink" title="Follow us on Twitter">Follow us on Twitter<span></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="linkedinlink" style="display:none;" class="linkedin linkedinlink" title="Follow us on LinkedIn">Follow us on LinkedIn<span></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for any help here with this issue that I've tred so many possible solutions but for not the right one.

Comment: I'm confused. The regex you linked to obviously can't match if it expects `href` in a place where there's `id` in the text. If one single token of a regex can't match, the entire regex fails. It appears you are expecting parts of the regex to somehow find a way to match independently of the rest of the regex. Are you? This is not how regexes work.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, in case the href is missing from one of the elements, at least it will match the others which have it. A conditional regex statement that I really don't know how to do it. I've even tried the `(?:(href="(.*?)"))` but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I don‘t think that that’s possible with only one regex. You could first find the `ul` tags and then search those substrings. But generally, regexes are not a good tool for matching HTML.

Comment: I think I have a solution for this issue. I'll be testing and if it works as expected, I'll post it here as reply that solves the issue.

Comment: Would this work for you? [`<a.*(?:href="([^"]+?)").*<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/MKmmbo/1)

Comment: Thanks Matt, but it doesn't. I'm posting down the solution that works. Kind of a hack but it works like charm, although a bit expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to my question and after several attempts to solve the issue with regex as the problems states and also with the help of people who have came here to try to hand me a hand on the problem, I found a solution that works for the missing `href=""` attribute on the element.

Since the result of the `curl` may come with or without it, but the block is always there, I just added the following php code for the three links:

```
$result = str_replace('<a id="facebooklink"','<a href="NULL" id="facebooklink"', $result);
$result = str_replace('<a id="twitterlink"','<a href="NULL" id="twitterlink"', $result);
$result = str_replace('<a id="linkedinlink"','<a href="NULL" id="linkedinlink"', $result);
```

What this does is that adds the missing `href=""` from the element and now, even if one fails, the others return the match.

Kind of a hack and a bit expensive but not so worried about it at this point as the system deals with it very well.

Comment: Quite hacky :-) Why don't you get the content of the div with `/<ul class="social">(.*)<\/ul>/gUms` and look for each link with something like `/<a href="(.*?)" id="twitterlink"/gUms`. Wrap it up in a function to return the map of the three link addresses.

Comment: I've tried that Christoph but found some non matches along the way. This hacky system is working like charm now :) No failures. Thanks btw.